# dt_text to dt_str conversion using c# in Script component SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to convert dt_text (blob) to dt_str varchar(max) in C# using scriptcomponent SSIS , i cannot use dataconversion transformation as it limits the character to 8000 characters, i have  important information in the text field with more than 10000 characters(lot of notes information).

I started with the example posted online

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;    // Added
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
// Method that will be executed for each row.
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (!Row.Description_IsNull) 
    {
        cont.description = 
            System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(
                Row.Description.GetBlobData(
                    0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.Description.Length)));
    } 
}
```

while building I got the following error message not sure what im missing here . Im new to C# code ..
(Error  2   'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetBlobData' and no extension method 'GetBlobData' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your "Description" column on your input row is DT_TEXT? Check your input. GetBlobData is a method on the "BlobColumn" data type - it looks like the source column is of the "String" data type. Look in the BufferWrapper.cs generated file, see if a column of type BlobColumn is in there.. if not, you need to check your input fields.

Comment: I have tried to change the datatype to varchar(max) by casting in the sql query and in the advanced options of DFT i have forced it to dt_str(8k) characrtes but now the description column is at DT_TEXT and i still have the same error message .  ****The type or namespace name 'Description' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) *is* dt_text. If you are going from and to VARCHAR(MAX), don't convert it at all. dt_str is VARCHAR(8000). There's good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705639/how-to-transfer-data-using-ssis-when-database-columns-are-defined-as-varcharmax

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having that you need it to be DT_STR?

Comment: I should convert the source column which is in "ntext" in my sql query before i pick distinct records , so i cast it to varchar(max) and push it down stream where the column passes thru the script component containing C# regular expressions which removes the HTML tags like these and processes only SQL SERVER ** updated         <span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Verdana','sans-serif'"><strong><u> SQL SERVER- **updated<o:p></o:p></u></strong></span><p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt">   Initially the business were ok with 8k characters but important info is between 9k and 15k so need all